# Window inactivity alarm

Tags: c++, windows, ui-automation

So I have a new project idea..
My girlfriend plays this MMORPG, and she often leaves her character to do something (eg. fishing) in the background, but if she doesn't click in the window for 5 minutes it logs her automatically.
So my idea is to make some sort of an "alarm", where if the window the game is in is inactive for about 4 minutes, it pops up a message box telling her to click in it.

Can any of you give me somewhere to start on this?

Comment: Detecting activity in *another* window is actually a fairly complex task -- perhaps not the best choice for a complete novice.

Comment: Agree with above.  You would have to write a program that isolates the popup window of the MMORPG somehow, hopefully easily by searching for its title and getting its windows handle, and then locate the close button on it and send a mouse click message to it.  Not something that is easily done.  Perhaps there are free GUI testing tools out there that you can get which will do this for you.  Though I'm guessing this is against the EULA of the game.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume this popup is a WinAPI window. I guess most modern games uses their own GUIs, which would render below idea useless.

I would start with Spy++ (from Visual Studio), when this popup window shows up, use Spy++ to find its window. Note its name and class name. With those two you can use FindWindow to check if it popups up. You just make a loop and periodically check if FindWindow(szPopupWndName, szPopupClassName) returns non null value. If it is non null then inform that window button in MMORG must be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something similar to:

```
//when the window loses focus, start a timer.
//when timer reaches 4 min...
//get all windows,
//sort them,
//find the one you need
//give it focus for 0.1s then go back to whatever you were doing
```

I don't know exactly how you can do it, but I broke it up into smaller subjects so you can look into them, more precisely:

- detecting a windows state (maybe through an injected dll? I don't know)
- timer (very easy in .NET)
- giving windows focus as a program.